# Insert simple menu into css to use as web page header

Tags: html, css, button, css-tables

I am creating a simple webpage with header and footer using CSS. I wanted my web page header (built by CSS) to include a simple navigation menu as such:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
              WebPage Header (Appears on every page)
                          Image Logo

    Home    |    News    |    Event    |    Contact Us    <-- How to do this is CSS to appear in all pages?
------------------------------------------------------------


                       Body Content

------------------------------------------------------------
          WebPage Footer (Appears on every page)
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have already come out with the header and footer definition in CSS as below.

```
hr {color:sienna;}
p {margin-left:20px;}

header 
{
height: 192px;
background:#ffffff url("images/logo.jpg") no-repeat center top;
//How to add navigating buttons here?
}

footer 
{
height: 192px;
}
```

I did quite a bit of research already, but most online tutorial uses different approach (e.g: php). w3schools did not go too much in depth as well.

Answer (score 1):

First:
You can't add in every pages a footer or navigation bar or something else without the help of Javascript or PHP or another language. HTML and CSS are static and with CSS3 you are able to add a kind of label for each element, not a structure.

Unique way to do in HTML it's to use FRAMES*, but it's an ugly and old way.
[Docs here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp), but really, don't use frames if not for an homework.

However, if you copy and paste a code like this in each page:

```
<div id="top_menu">
    <ul id="nav_bar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="events.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

you can style this menu as you need in css like this

```
#nav_bar li{
 display: inline;
 padding: 3px; //just a sample 
}

#nav_bar a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Example of frames:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<frameset rows="25%,*,25%">
  <frame src="header.html">
  <frame name="openhere" src="frame_b.htm">
  <frame src="footer.htm">
</frameset>

</html>
```

so put in a page "header.html" your navigation bar (add in links `attribute: target="openhere"`)

*remember that tag FRAME it's not more supported in HTML5. So... avoid if you can!

Comment: I totally agree with you on frames. I tried frames earlier, but it looks terrible even though it works to certain extent. CSS allows me to add image into <header></header> so that when I paste <header></header> into subsequent html files, it shows the image dynamically. My question is: is it possible to add text and tables too (instead of images) into CSS <header></header>?

Comment: No. Image is a "style" for something. A table or a div is an element. All you can it's insert some text, like a label, but nothing more... since "a label" can be considered like a style (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp). What you are looking for it's a template with fixed part and this is Frame in HTML or include in PHP or some dynamic change of DOM in page via  javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Put all links to centered div, and use styled `<ul>`:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>News</li>
        <li>Events</li>
        <li>Contact us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, you mean placing those div tags in the CSS file?

Comment: @user3437460 Not divs itself, only style for it must go to css file.

Comment: @Jusitnas Mind elaborate how it is going to work in CSS. I tried many combinations but CSS just won't work with tags. Sry, I am new to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to change your html pages to php so you can easily include your
 header file in all other pages or Make a simple frame to navigate between pages....